# How to change a local class varible node js

Tags: node.js

I don't really know how to explain this but I will try my best

so I have a Card class in the file `card.js` that look like this:

```
class card {
    constructor(name = "", portrait = "", bloodCost = 0, boneCost = 0, power = 0, health = 1, sigilList = []) {
        this.name = name
        this.portrait = portrait;
        this.bloodCost = bloodCost;
        this.boneCost = boneCost;
        this.power = power;
        this.health = health;
        this.sigilList = sigilList;
    }
    attack(sigilList = [], board = [], oppositeCard = new card(), scale = 0) {
        var oppositeCardHealth = 0
        if (oppositeCard == blank) {
            scale += this.power;
        }
        else {
            oppositeCardHealth += this.power;
        }
        return [scale, oppositeCardHealth];
    };

var wolf = new card("Wolf", ":wolf:", 2, 0, 3, 2);
module.exports = { wolf };
}
```

And a 'main.js' file like this:

```
const cardLib = require("./lib/card");
var broad = [cardLib.wolf, cardLib.wolf]
broad[0].health -= 2;
console.log(broad);
```

So what I want to do is only changing the health of the wolf in broad[0] with out changing the other one health. Which mean the program should return something like this:

```
[
  card {
    name: 'Wolf',      
    portrait: ':wolf:',
    bloodCost: 2,      
    boneCost: 0,       
    power: 3,
    health: 0,
    sigilList: []      
  },
  card {
    name: 'Wolf',      
    portrait: ':wolf:',
    bloodCost: 2,      
    boneCost: 0,
    power: 3,
    health: 2,
    sigilList: []
  }
]
```

Comment: You probably need to new two `wolf` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, `wolf` is a specific instance of a `card`. Your array has two references to the same object, so changing one of them will change them "both".

One approach could be to not hold a `wolf` variable, but instead provide a function to create such a wolf card:

```
// card.js:
class card {
     // constructor and attack unchanged, removed for brevity's sake
}

var wolf = () => new card("Wolf", ":wolf:", 2, 0, 3, 2);
module.exports = { wolf };

// main.js:
const cardLib = require("./lib/card");
var broad = [cardLib.wolf(), cardLib.wolf()]; // wolf is a function that creates a a card
broad[0].health -= 2;
console.log(broad);
```

Comment: With the way you are doing this when i try `cardLib.wolf()` it return `cardLib.wolf() is not a function`

Comment: @MaxNguyen had a typo there (`->` should be `=>`, and the wolf variable should be outside the class), sorry. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
var broad = [cardLib.wolf, cardLib.wolf]
```

Put's two references to the exact same wolf object in your array.  So, naturally, if you change one, the other will appear changed also because both spots in the array point at the exact same object.

If you want two separate, independent objects in the array, then you have to create two separate objects by creating a separate card.  To do that from outside that file, it would be best to export the Card constructor so you can call it and create a separate card to put into the array.  Another option would be to add a `.copy()` method to your Card object so you can create a copy of an existing object.

---

Here's an example of a `.copy()` method:

```
class card {
    constructor(name = "", portrait = "", bloodCost = 0, boneCost = 0, power = 0, health = 1, sigilList = []) {
        this.name = name
        this.portrait = portrait;
        this.bloodCost = bloodCost;
        this.boneCost = boneCost;
        this.power = power;
        this.health = health;
        this.sigilList = sigilList;
    }
    attack(sigilList = [], board = [], oppositeCard = new card(), scale = 0) {
        var oppositeCardHealth = 0
        if (oppositeCard == blank) {
            scale += this.power;
        } else {
            oppositeCardHealth += this.power;
        }
        return [scale, oppositeCardHealth];
    }
    copy() {
        let newCard = new card(
            this.name, 
            this.portrait, 
            this.bloodCost,
            this.boneCost,
            this.power,
            this.health,
            this.sigilList.slice(0);
        )
        return newCard;
    }
}

let wolf = new card("Wolf", ":wolf:", 2, 0, 3, 2);
module.exports = { wolf };
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
let broad = [cardLib.wolf, cardLib.wolf.copy()];
```

---

This implementation assumes that none of the instance variables except `sigilList` are objects that have to be copied themselves in order to be separate and that the `sigilList` array can be shallow copied with `.slice(0)` in order to be independent.

Comment: So is there anyway that I can avoid doing that because for what I'm doing I'm gonna make a lot of the same card but in different place because it a card game

Comment: @MaxNguyen - If you want the cards to be different, you have to create different objects, either by calling the Card constructor separately or by creating a `.copy()` method that would make a copy of an existing card.

Comment: @MaxNguyen - I added an example of a `.copy()` method that will allow you to create separate objects from an original object.