# How do I run every exported function

Tags: node.js

So i have this mess of a js file

```
cardPool = []

class Card {
    constructor(name = "", portrait = "", bloodCost = 0, boneCost = 0, power = 0, health = 1, sigilList = ["No sigil"]) {
        this.name = name
        this.portrait = portrait;
        this.bloodCost = bloodCost;
        this.boneCost = boneCost;
        this.power = power;
        this.health = health;
        this.sigilList = sigilList;
        cardPool.push(this)
    }

    Damage(dmg = 1) {
        this.health -= dmg
    }
}

blank = new Card("blank", "");
income = new Card("income", "⬇️");

module.exports = {
    Card,

    blank,
    income,

    bear: function () { new Card("Grizzly", "", 3, 0, 4, 6) },
    wolf: function () { new Card("Wolf", "", 2, 0, 3, 2) },

    cardPool,
};
```

All I want to do is on start up it run all of the function being exported. There more function that I export but here only a few so stack overflow won't scream at me. This is for a game that I'm making to be able to handle multiple instance of the same card. You can read about why I make new card using function here: [How to change a local class varible node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228044/how-to-change-a-local-class-varible-node-js) . And I need a card pool so that I can do stuff in another file here my other question: [How can i put an object inside a list on Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70480658/how-can-i-put-an-object-inside-a-list-on-initialization). Now I need on startup put all the card that I make in the module.export in the cardPool.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a case of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you exactly trying to achieve with this program? There are probably better ways to do it.

Comment: Use a loop and test if the item is a function, if so, call it.

Comment: @CoderCharmander I edit my question a bit does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be placing the functions in some kind of container (for example an array or a map) (in case you later want to export other functions from the file that don't create cards). Here's the simplest way with an array:

```js
// Note the return statements! The functions will not return anything without them!
function bear () { return new Card("Grizzly", "", 3, 0, 4, 6) }
function wolf () { return new Card("Wolf", "", 2, 0, 3, 2) }

module.exports = {
    // ...
    
    cardCreatorFunctions: [bear, wolf, /* and maybe others */],
}
```

Then, you can iterate through the array and push created cards into `cardPool` one-by-one:

```js
for (let fun of cardLib.cardCreatorFunctions) {
    cardLib.cardPool.push(fun())
}
```

Or you can do it in one statement:

```js
cardLib.cardPool = cardLib.cardCreatorFunctions.map(fun => fun())
```